# How to alter time and date stamp of PE32

Tags: assembly, disassembly, ida

Where would I need to look to change the time and date stamp of a PE32 file? I apologize if this is too open ended, perhaps someone here can point me in the right direction or to the correct resource. I've been looking around to no avail.

I have access to a wide array of reverse engineering tools such as IDAPRo, PEBear, etc etc

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure to change the `TimeDateStamp` of a PE32 executable (`.exe` or `.dll`) is simple and can be derived from [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx).

- Find the "real" header by *by looking up its starting offset, which is stored in the MS-DOS stub header.*
- Calculate its address:

  ```
  pNTHeader = dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew;
  ```
- Now you have the `IMAGE_NT_HEADER` which is defined as follows in `WinNT.h`

  ```
  DWORD Signature;
  IMAGE_FILE_HEADER FileHeader;
  IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER OptionalHeader;
  ```
- Parse the the `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`
- Change the DWORD `TimeDateStamp` field as you like